# Get variable by ajax inside a function (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax-call function that works well, it alerts a variable that I want to use in another jquery functions:

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=marketfilter&m=getmax',
            method: "get",
        }).done(function (h) {
            d = $.parseJSON(h);
            myvar = (d.count);
            alert(myvar);
        });
});
```

myvar at this point is correct

How can I use myvar in another function?
For example

```
$(function() {
    var optmax = myvar; // Get max value from datatbase 
    var opt1 = optmax - 100;
    $('#price11 option').filter(function() {
      return parseInt(this.value, 10) > opt1;
    }).remove();
    $('#price22 option').filter(function() {
      return parseInt(this.value, 10) > optmax;
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: Run the second code block in the done() also. You could wrap it in a function and just call that function in done() and pass the count into the function as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use myvar in another function?

Pass the variable in a call to the function

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=marketfilter&m=getmax',
        method: "get",
    }).done(function (h) {
        d = $.parseJSON(h);
        myvar = (d.count);
        alert(myvar);
        myFunction(myvar)
    });
    function myFunction(myvar) {
        var optmax = myvar;  
        var opt1 = optmax - 100;
        $('#price11 option').filter(function() {
          return parseInt(this.value, 10) > opt1;
        }).remove();
        $('#price22 option').filter(function() {
          return parseInt(this.value, 10) > optmax;
        }).remove();
    } 
});
```